# How to download file from website at the same time everyday?

Tags: google-chrome, download

I want to download the files from the URL below every day at 8pm to a certain folder on my desktop. I have zero coding experience, so I have no idea how to accomplish this task whatsoever so I would appreciate the help!

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

Comment: Please specify Operating System you are using/willing to use for this task.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you use Windows)

- You need a program called "**git**" - go here **https://git-scm.com/** and download the appropriate version
- When you install it, take the default options (you won't be using most of git, so they don't matter)
- run **Git-CMD**
- type: **git clone https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/** *yourFolderName*

This will download the entire directory structure
Scheduling Windows jobs is a hassle.  Once you have this running, if you still think you need to schedule the task, say so and we'll explain the rest